# How does electricity actually work?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electricity, field-theory

This question is not similar to what I have read so far in this site. I am just trying to understand what electricity actually is. I have come to know that when charges move or vibrate in a wire by the supplied voltage, the electrons drift velocity is very slow. And the bulb glows instantly because energy travels through EM field, which is perpendicular to electric and magnetic field. Now, comes the question, suppose if I create a circuit, and connect it to the battery. So, the bulb will glow, but what if I put another unconnected wire near the circuit connected with another bulb. Will the bulb glow? Because electricity travels through EM field. Shouldn't the bulb glow? Which actually doesn't happen. I am just confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327787/why-do-electrons-follow-the-conductors-shape

Comment: The wire acts like a waveguide for the EM field. The EM field energy isn't just messily spilling out everywhere into space. I don't really know the specifics though.

Comment: More broadly: Introduction to How Electricity Works is the kind of topic for which one usually has a book or two directed towards undergraduate physics students. You can find an introductory course for free here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-02-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2019/

Comment: It's possible, provided, amongst other things, there is a time-varying current in the first circuit. See [electromagnetic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction).

Answer (score 1):

> energy travels through EM field, which is perpendicular to electric and magnetic field.

The EM field isn't perpendicular to the electric and magnetic filed. The EM field **is** the electric and magnetic fields, considered as two aspects of a single phenomenon. That's what the E and M stand for.

> suppose if I create a circuit, and connect it to the battery. So, the bulb will glow, but what if I put another unconnected wire near the circuit connected with another bulb. Will the bulb glow?

Assuming you're asking about a circuit with DC (not time varying) currents, potentials, and fields, then no. Although the electrons in the wire move relatively slowly, nonetheless they do move, and in this scenario they will move in the second wire in such a way as to negate the field from the first wire, and no current will flow in the second wire (or the second bulb).

As mentioned in the comments, in an AC circuit it is possible to arrange the wires in such a way that you could make the second bulb glow. You would be essentially making a transformer out of the two wires. If you want energy to be transferred efficiently, you might want to use a "core" of an appropriate material between the two wires to guide the magnetic fields in a way that couples the two wires strongly.

Comment: I understood a few things here. I am actually really new to it. I am asking, if electron drift velocity is very slow, then how does the filament glow? I just veritasium video on electricity, he said they get enough energy from EM field. And energy flow perpendicular to both E and M field. When an unconnected wire get the energy from the field of the closed Circuit, then why doesn't it glow?

Comment: https://youtu.be/oI_X2cMHNe0

Comment: Please, explain what he is saying at 13:00 and after that.

Comment: @ShubhamSingh, think of waves in the ocean. The individual water molecules never move, but the wave still conveys energy. The moving water at the end can be used to drive a generator, despite the molecules not having come from somewhere else. The same way, the electrons flowing through the filament don't have to come from far away to transfer the energy of the EM wave into the filament and produce heat (and a small amount of light).

Answer (score 0):

It is true that electricity consists of EM waves, but those aren't just due to the electrons. The EM field is created due to **moving** electrons. Whenever a charged particle is moving, there is an EM field created. But if the particle is at rest, there won't be any field. Thus, only when electrons move through the circuit is when these fields would exist.

When you put an unconnected wire near a closed circuit, there are no electrons moving *from* the circuit *to* the unconnected wire. Due to this, there is no EM field created in that wire and thus no electricity. Another possible answer could be that, if there aren't any electrons jumping from the circuit to the wire, then how could there be electricity in the first place? After all, electricity is electric current, which means moving electrons. Thus, there couldn't possibly be electricity flowing into the unconnected wire by either EM waves (created by moving electrons, just to remind you) or electrons themselves.